# ipython-qtconsole: change size of displayed plot

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, scipy, ipython

I want to use `ipython` to display plots. I start it as:

```
ipython qtconsole --pylab=inline
```

the plots are drawn inline, and seem to have fixed size. Is there any way, once the plot is drawn, to drag the plot element  with the mouse in the corner, and enlarge it? What I have in mind is similar functionality as `Mathematica` has

Comment: You can call figsize() before it's displayed to change the size, but I don't think there's a way to resize them afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way (currently) to resize the plots by simple mouse drags. I think most of us find the default figure size to be too small. This can be changed by modifying the `ipython` profiles.

You can resize the plot by mouse in `ipython notebook`.

Locate:

```
# Subset of matplotlib rcParams that should be different for the inline backend.
# c.InlineBackend.rc = {'font.size': 10, 'figure.figsize': (6.0, 4.0), 'figure.facecolor': (1, 1, 1, 0), 'savefig.dpi': 72, 'figure.subplot.bottom': 0.125, 'figure.edgecolor': (1, 1, 1, 0)}
```

Uncomment the 2nd line and change the figure size `(6.4, 4.0)` to desired size.

For `ipython-notebook`, modify the `ipython_notebook_config.py` file. For `ipython-qtconsole`, change the `ipython_qtconsole_config.py` file.

Comment: perfect, thanks. As a side note: while you can resize the plot in `ipython notebook`, it resizes the image with the existing (low) resolution.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Spyder, you can set figures to draw in their own pop-up window, and then you can resize them freely from there. Check out this guide for details:
https://www.scivision.co/spyder-with-ipython-make-matplotlib-plots-appear-in-own-window/